# iOS Refresh location timestamp without movement

Tags: ios, location

I am creating an app on the iOS that can keep track of the location of the device. In order to check if the location of the device is recent, I used the following code to compare the timestamp of the location and the current time.

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
location = [locations lastObject];
NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"%f",howRecent);
}
```

However, the problem with that is if the device is stationary in one location, the delegate doesn't get called and the time interval keeps increasing. As such, I am wondering is there a better way in retrieving the age of the location by forcing a refresh of the location update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSTimer to refresh it

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setLastActivityTime:[NSDate date]];
    [self setStatusTimer:[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(updateStatus:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:[self statusTimer] forMode:[self runLoopMode]];
}

- (void)updateStatus:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    [locationmanager startUpdatingLocation]; // this will call didUpdateLocations delegate

    if (![self inProgress]) {
        [self setStatusTimer:nil];
    }
}
- (void)setStatusTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self retain];
    // We must invalidate the old timer here, not before we've created and scheduled a new timer
    // This is because the timer may be the only thing retaining an asynchronous request
    if (statusTimer && timer != statusTimer) {
        [statusTimer invalidate];
        [statusTimer release];
    }
    statusTimer = [timer retain];
    [self release];
}
```

I hope it will help you.